# Wordpress Plugin Look & Feel

Tags: plugins, admin, css, design

Is there a list of the ID's and Classes I can give HTML elements in the admin panel in order to closely mimic the wordpress look and feel?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Onextrapixel's blog post [How To Design And Style Your WordPress Plugin Admin Panel](http://www.onextrapixel.com/2009/07/01/how-to-design-and-style-your-wordpress-plugin-admin-panel/) isn't an official reference, but it is a nicely detailed one.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't an official reference, but they're easy enough to spot using Chrome's or Firebug's "Inspect Element" option.

Comment: an official list would be much better. Would be able to think about ways to do things ahead, rather than having to find an instance of it being done, and copy it.

Comment: @Mild Fuzz - I know what you mean, but Scribu is right, there is no such an official list and I won't expect one to appear the sooner or later. Perhaps this becomes more easy after the admin is more strictly modularized, proposed in http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/11517 and which links a lot of related tickets as well.

Answer (score 1):

I had just recently picked up (form comment in some question here) this - [WordPress.org UI Styleguide](http://dotorgstyleguide.wordpress.com/). It seems to be official (linked to from [UI development blog](http://make.wordpress.org/ui/) at least).